# What are my options if I want to package my resources into a runnable JAR (without using Class Loader)?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, classloader, executable

I want to create a runnable jar for my GUI program with images and html files. I have my html and images folder placed in the root folder of the eclipse project. For example, I have an eclipse project with the subdirectories bin, html, images, src,  and .settings.

I heard that Java's Class Loader would make it easy for me to package my program resources and source code. But that would mean I would have to place my resource files along with the class files. I'm not used to doing that and would prefer to organize my resources the way I currently have it.

I've never used Maven or Ant and would like to know if it can be done with these tools.

What are my options to solve this problem if there are any?

Comment: Why do you care whether the images are in under the `src` folder or not? That said, you should definitely learn using build tools, and yes, they will allow storing images in a separate directory.

Answer (score 0):

For small config files, put those in $project_dir/src/main/resources, and they will get built into your final .jar file. Logging configuration files, for example, are ideal for this.

If you have large data, like images, I'd probably keep them separate from the .jar and just distribute in a "data" folder next to the jar.

Ant/Maven are the major Java build tools. Gradle is arguably better and easier than those if you have the choice. You can make a one line Gradle script `apply plugin: 'java'` and put your .java source in src/main/java and your resources in src/main/resources and run `gradle jar` and that should work.

Comment: Your second suggestion sounds like a good idea once the project gets too big. I'm not sure how to do this, though. One hurdle that I have is distributing in different systems. I want to create an executable jar with no install required. I guess I can place my jar and resources in the same folder. So my hurdle is how to deal with the relative path of my resources so the jar has access to its resources (as long as relative path is unchanged).

Comment: @poetryrocksalot: frankly, I don't see what you would gain, except complexity, by not bundling the images inside the jar. KISS.

Comment: @nizet, I wouldn't put large files in a .jar. If nothing else, because every build will need to copy and zip all of those files.

Comment: @poetryrocksalot, just access with a relative path like "./data/images/image.png". On startup, your code should probably verify that "./data" exists. You don't need an install step, but you probably want a directory with the .jar and the `data` directory

Comment: I decided to just use the Class Loader to load all resources from the bin directory.